# Ubuntu server wont start — SSD drive with no partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery

I have an Ubuntu server 16.04 in an Intel Nuc NUC7PJYH at home.
It has been working nicely for a year now; but this morning it was off. Didn't run any command before stopped running.
I tried to turn it on and it was not detecting any bootable device.
The Server is connected to the outside world via a Mikrotik HAP2 router with proper firewall confs.
I don't have critical data, but I use it a lot, and don't want to reset and recofigure it if possible.
I downloaded last Ubuntu desktop and installed it into an USB; started the Intel Nuc with it, and run some tests following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks

First tried to check the disks:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ sudo fdisk -l
[…]
Disk /dev/sda: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: SATAFIRM   S11  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
[…]
Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *          0  5619583  5619584  2.7G  0 Empty
/dev/sdc2          1700     9699     8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdc3       5619712 61439999 55820288 26.6G 83 Linux
```

Then tried to mount my ssd

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ sudo mkdir /mnt/MOUNTED_DRIVE
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ sudo mount -v /dev/sda /mnt/MOUNTED_DRIVE
mount: /mnt/MOUNTED_DRIVE: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Tried to see what fdisk returns:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: SATAFIRM   S11  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Used fsck:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sda
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I run e2fsck with same result:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sda
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

dumpe2fs returns the backup blocks

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda
dumpe2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Creating filesystem with 29305206 4k blocks and 7331840 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 6710bdb4-5f0c-4b29-b2d4-d40e98e34748
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
```

So now I try to recover a block:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Finally, I tried to use testdisk, which says `Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55`

```
TestDisk 7.2-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, Novembre 2020
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 120 GB / 111 GiB - CHS 14593 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors


Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55
```

At this point I'm starting to think if someone has entered in my network and erased this hard drive, but I think I have both the Firewall rules in the router and in the server well configured. The other option is that the disk just died, but it seems quite unusual to me.

Any help will be welcome

-- Edit:
As recommended by @happyTusk I run `fsck -p`, but same result:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -p /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.34
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
/dev/sda: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Answer (score 0):

Definite possibility of dead drive or just massive irreparable corruption. Try `fsck -p /dev/sda` to see if the repair if possible by it option will work. Took about a day on my 6TB hard drive but got it back for me in the end.

Comment: Will run it. So is this possible, that a disk can be deeply corrupted by itself?

Comment: The file system on it certainly can be. If it is the low level corruption then the disk is dying that is the hardware, file system, if it gets bad data sent to it, this causes the file system problems.

Comment: Run it, same result... edited the question to add the log

Comment: Wipe it and see if it will work with new file system on it, if not then its off to be recycled then, it is dead.

Comment: So is THAT corrupted? By itself? I'm absolutely amazed that this is the reliability of an SSD.

Comment: It happens, not by itself, by something going wrong in the computer when it is writing to the drive. As the old saying in computers goes garbage in/ garbage out. If it continues to happen their is hardware fault somewhere, ram, motherboard i/o to the controller, drive going to die and has problems storing the information on the cells... gamma radiation if the ECC ram people are to be believed. Who knows what else can go wrong with it, in computers I have seen some strange things in my 40+ years of messing with them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I knew that a tiny Intel Nuc for a server was going to be tigth, but didn't expect that. Thankfully the data was replicated in other two devices; but now I understand why I have to buy a regular server for my needs. Thanks!